# How to compare two lists in python, but part of the values

Tags: python

For example lest say I have those two lists:

```
x = ["hi [ICON]", "apple [ICON]", "world [ICON]" ]
y = ["hi", "apple"]
```

How can I tell if all of list `y` is inside of list `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `any` and `all`.

```
# First check each element of 'y' exist in at least one element of  'x'
>>> [any(i in j for j in x) for i in y]
[True, True]

# Second check all elements of y exist in x.
>>> all(any(i in j for j in x) for i in y) # <- You need this check two steps
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution : `ly` is the set of all elements of y that exists in x elements.

```
ly={yi for yi in y for xi in x if yi in xi}
```

now, you can define a bool variable:

```
are_all_y_elt_in_x_elt = (len(ly)==len(y))
```

```
# EX. 1
# x = ["hi [ICON]", "apple [ICON]", "world [ICON]" ]
# y = ["hi", "apple", "world"]
# 
# are_all_y_elt_in_x_elt = True

# EX. 2
# x = ["hi [ICON]", "apple [ICON]", "world [ICON]" ]
# y = ["hi", "apple", "worlddd"]
# 
# are_all_y_elt_in_x_elt = False
```

Comment: This will not work properly if the arrays were like this:
x = ["hi [ICON]", "apple [ICON]", "world [ICON]", "another hi [ICON]"]
y = ["hi", "apple"]

Comment: Your are right, I edited my answer : It will work with a `set` instead of a `list`. Thanks. => `ly={yi for yi in y for xi in x if yi in xi}`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in many ways. I will write the most explanatory algorithm but not the more pythonic one.

You can concatenating all elements of the first list into a string and then search whether each element of the second list is contained in the string.

```py
combined = ' '.join(x)

your_bool = False  # init to false
for el in y:
    if el in combined:
        your_bool = True
    else:
        your_bool = False

print(your_bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether `y` is a subset of `x`, then the best approach is to use [`set` operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```py
>>> x = ["hi [ICON]", "apple [ICON]", "world [ICON]" ]
... y = ["hi", "apple"]

>>> set(y).issubset(set(x))
False
```

The reason the result for these is False is because of that `[ICON]` suffix in each element of `x`.  Example where it is True:

```py
>>> {1,2,3}.issubset({1,2,3,4,5})
True
```

If you just want to know whether any element of `x` contains a substring from `y`, then you could do the following on a per-element basis:

```py
>>> [any(a in word for a in y) for word in x]
[True, True, False]
```

...or the following for the full check:

```py
>>> all(any(a in word for a in y) for word in x)
False
```